# Add shortcut to section of long R script?

Tags: r, shortcut

I have a very long script with more than 5000 lines and I was wondering if I could add shortcuts to sections of the script.

I have separated my script into validation, prediction and figures. I would like to have little shortcut/link at the beginning of the script, so someone that wants to have a look at a part of my script doesn't have to scroll down.

Does anybody knows if such things exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RStudio, if you put four `#`'s on each side of a comment on its own line, RStudio will mark it as a section that can be navigated to by clicking on it at the bottom of the source code window. It should read 'Top Level' by default.

Example:

`#### Calculate standard deviation and moving average ####`

[image: Default Button]

[image: Option after adding block comment]